# Is Ubuntu's libsdl2-dev package missing dependencies or have I made a mistake?

Tags: dependencies, compiling, 22.04, sdl, ld

I am trying to compile the transport simulation [Simutrans-Extended](https://github.com/jamespetts/simutrans-extended). I have built it many times on Focal Fossa.

Today I tried to build it on Kubuntu Jammy Jellyfish. The build failed with the following errors from the linker:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -ldrm: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgbm: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -ldecor-0: No such file or directory
```

Installing the libdrm-dev, libgbm-dev, and libdecor-0-dev packages solved that problem. But I wonder whether it might be a packaging bug.

Those libraries are not direct dependencies of Simutrans. However, Ubuntu's sdl2-0-0 package has added dependencies on libgbm1, libdrm2, and libdecor-0-0 (compare [Focal](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/libsdl2-2.0-0) and [Jammy](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/libsdl2-2.0-0) dependencies). The libsdl2-dev package [does **not**](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/libsdl2-dev) list dependencies on the appropriate development packages.

I notice that SDL's own build guide [has listed those packages](https://github.com/libsdl-org/SDL/blob/main/docs/README-linux.md) as dependencies for building SDL2 itself on Focal Fossa [since February 2021](https://github.com/libsdl-org/SDL/commit/2f4e9294aa260635d876b5699846adc458f555db).

So did my build fail because Ubuntu's libsdl2-dev package is missing dependencies? If so, then I guess I will report that as a bug. But I am a newbie coder so I wondered if there's a more obvious explanation, since it's more likely that I made a mistake than Canonical/Debian package maintainers.

Comment: For one, I'm surprised you need to install `libdrm-dev` to fix "-ldrm: No such file or directory" - `libdrm.so.2` is provided by the [`libdrm2`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/amd64/libdrm2/filelist) package. Is that the complete error? If it's just missing shared libraries, you wouldn't need the `-dev` packages, which typically provide headers, not the shared library files.

Comment: @muru Thank you for the response. That makes sense to me but libbgm1 and libdrm2 were already installed when the error was reported, as dependencies of libsdl2-2.0-0, so that wasn't the issue. Is it possible that autotools needed the -dev packages to find libdrm.so.2 etc.?

Comment: Hmm. No, I was wrong, the `-dev` packages provide the plain`.so` files needed for linking. Yes, this seems like a packaging bug, especially since the linker flags adding these dependencies are from the `libsdl-dev` package's `/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/cmake/SDL2/sdl2-config.cmake` file. Please file a bug report.